# Eclipse Android ADT plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

Ive downloaded this version and followed all the steps. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
The proplem is when I go to Window -> Preferences -> Android none of the SDK locations I select will allow me to apply them

Comment: Consider using [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) if you just started developing for Android

Comment: I have to use this version for a university project

Comment: Okay. Sorry I can't help you with Eclipse, have not used it for a while.